# Successfully deployed Django to Heroku but received application error

Tags: python, django, heroku, deployment, terminal

**EDIT**:

I included all requirements inside the pipfile and removed the requirements.txt file. Looks like the application works now BUT stuck on "Not Found. The requested resource was not found on this server" (line 24 in the Heroku log below). I've updated Heroku log, pipfile, Procfile, and settings.py:

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn myquiz.wsgi --log-file -
```

**pipfile**

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
djangorestframework = "==3.12.2"
django-nested-admin = "==3.3.3"
asgiref = "==3.3.1"
click = "==7.1.2"
dj-database-url = "==0.5.0"
django-cors-headers = "==3.7.0"
django-heroku = "==0.3.1"
gunicorn = "==20.0.4"
itsdangerous = "==1.1.0"
psycopg2 = "==2.7.7"
python-decouple = "==3.4"
python-monkey-business = "==1.0.0"
pytz = "==2021.1"
six = "==1.15.0"
sqlparse = "==0.4.1"
whitenoise = "==5.2.0"
Django = "==3.1.6"
Flask = "==1.1.2"
Jinja2 = "==2.11.3"
MarkupSafe = "==1.1.1"
Werkzeug = "==1.0.1"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

**Settings.py**

```
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
from decouple import config


# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = ''

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'rest_framework',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'quizzes',
    'nested_admin',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myquiz.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "TEMPLATES")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myquiz.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


### Sessions
SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db"


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/images/'


# Extra places for collectstatic to find static files #
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')



STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'



django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**Heroku logs --tail**

```
2021-02-06T05:48:46.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T05:49:50.182826+00:00 app[api]: Release v50 created by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T05:49:50.182826+00:00 app[api]: Deploy cde348a6 by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T05:49:50.754717+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-02-06T05:49:50.758453+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-02-06T05:49:51.838368+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-02-06T05:49:51.924678+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:49:51 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-02-06T05:49:51.924700+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:49:51 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-02-06T05:49:51.924848+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:49:51 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-02-06T05:49:52.125735+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:49:52 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-02-06T05:49:52.213682+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-02-06T05:50:01.596314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myquiz.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-02-06T05:50:04.671514+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:50:04 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-02-06T05:50:04.672057+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:50:04 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:31749 (4)
2021-02-06T05:50:04.672145+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:50:04 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-02-06T05:50:04.676034+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:50:04 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-02-06T05:50:04.703124+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:50:04 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-02-06T05:50:04.981300+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2021-02-06T05:50:04.981337+00:00 app[web.1]: """)
2021-02-06T05:50:05.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-06T05:50:05.086614+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2021-02-06T05:50:05.086615+00:00 app[web.1]: """)
2021-02-06T05:50:06.397214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-06T05:50:08.667840+00:00 app[web.1]: Not Found: /
2021-02-06T05:50:08.667985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=38245610-72e8-43ab-a8df-a4957a487d1e fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=125ms status=404 bytes=2400 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:50:08.668610+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.182.117.232 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:50:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2160 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T05:51:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T05:52:46.415468+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 4dc24524 by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T05:52:46.415468+00:00 app[api]: Release v51 created by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T05:52:46.627426+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-02-06T05:52:46.643392+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-02-06T05:52:47.560103+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-02-06T05:52:47.651176+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:52:47 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-02-06T05:52:47.651188+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:52:47 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-02-06T05:52:47.655456+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:52:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-02-06T05:52:47.756234+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:52:47 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-02-06T05:52:47.837959+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-02-06T05:52:58.498821+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myquiz.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-02-06T05:52:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-06T05:53:01.726865+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:53:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-02-06T05:53:01.728247+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:53:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:4937 (4)
2021-02-06T05:53:01.728526+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:53:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-02-06T05:53:01.735683+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:53:01 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-02-06T05:53:01.777357+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 05:53:01 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-02-06T05:53:02.387750+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2021-02-06T05:53:02.387775+00:00 app[web.1]: """)
2021-02-06T05:53:02.536880+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2021-02-06T05:53:02.536883+00:00 app[web.1]: """)
2021-02-06T05:53:03.181646+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-06T05:53:04.387317+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=a4297642-b4d0-45de-babf-2a9c51241934 fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=259ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:53:04.389696+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.173.187 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:53:04 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T05:53:22.042667+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=f321097c-5ffc-4e70-a7b7-46a65c544a3c fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=4ms status=301 bytes=256 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:53:22.043383+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.173.187 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:53:22 +0000] "GET /admin HTTP/1.1" 301 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T05:53:22.111918+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=6e155cc9-6fb6-4453-aeef-5d48af9d49b8 fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=46ms status=302 bytes=412 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:53:22.112587+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.173.187 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:53:22 +0000] "GET /admin/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T05:53:22.251424+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/admin/login/?next=/admin/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=54b20793-bb90-4104-ad3f-67c7f56bdab9 fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=112ms status=500 bytes=410 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:53:22.251635+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.173.187 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:53:22 +0000] "GET /admin/login/?next=/admin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 145 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T05:53:30.755350+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=ab0e2d59-10dd-4fd3-a26a-f68ecf7029ae fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=249ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:53:30.755735+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.173.187 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:53:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T05:54:30.547441+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=3818e9f2-d03b-48f5-99f8-1b5d38b134cf fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:54:30.548120+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.173.187 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:54:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T05:54:32.793597+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=c0690601-864c-4509-9f89-b116491a0b29 fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:54:32.794811+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.41.173.187 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:54:32 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T05:57:58.831607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=b8c546fb-b2bb-4058-b291-008716372822 fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-02-06T05:57:58.831767+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.69.237.10 - - [06/Feb/2021:05:57:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T06:00:09.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T06:01:11.742350+00:00 app[api]: Release v52 created by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T06:01:11.742350+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 097500b2 by user myemail@gmail.com
2021-02-06T06:01:11.962589+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2021-02-06T06:01:11.989798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2021-02-06T06:01:13.059167+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-02-06T06:01:13.115692+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:13 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-02-06T06:01:13.115706+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:13 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-02-06T06:01:13.117113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:13 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-02-06T06:01:13.316634+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:13 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-02-06T06:01:13.393689+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2021-02-06T06:01:19.035782+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn myquiz.wsgi --log-file -`
2021-02-06T06:01:21.013399+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:21 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-02-06T06:01:21.013943+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:21 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:10487 (4)
2021-02-06T06:01:21.014032+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:21 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-02-06T06:01:21.017760+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:21 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-02-06T06:01:21.047688+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:01:21 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-02-06T06:01:21.306613+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2021-02-06T06:01:21.306675+00:00 app[web.1]: """)
2021-02-06T06:01:21.328042+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-06T06:01:21.367731+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py:144: UserWarning: The psycopg2 wheel package will be renamed from release 2.8; in order to keep installing from binary please use "pip install psycopg2-binary" instead. For details see: <http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/install.html#binary-install-from-pypi>.
2021-02-06T06:01:21.367733+00:00 app[web.1]: """)
2021-02-06T06:01:24.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-02-06T06:02:08.151715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=fbee2c20-a1aa-4cf1-af50-6d4dbec7d81a fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=118ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-02-06T06:02:08.152268+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.13.235.87 - - [06/Feb/2021:06:02:08 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "https://dashboard.heroku.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T06:04:12.490929+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=d92d7123-c7f1-40da-8480-af4c574e2507 fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=119ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-02-06T06:04:12.490572+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.250.120 - - [06/Feb/2021:06:04:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T06:04:13.392300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=myquiz-20192020.herokuapp.com request_id=e8bd1876-cf0f-4da7-b669-f5610aaa9600 fwd="74.101.138.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=3ms status=404 bytes=418 protocol=https
2021-02-06T06:04:13.386873+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.35.250.120 - - [06/Feb/2021:06:04:13 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 179 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 11_2_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"
2021-02-06T06:38:43.842393+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-02-06T06:38:43.846084+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-02-06T06:38:44.971060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-02-06T06:38:45.031279+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:38:45 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-02-06T06:38:45.033378+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:38:45 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-02-06T06:38:45.062285+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:38:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Handling signal: term
2021-02-06T06:38:45.166985+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-02-06 06:38:45 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-02-06T06:38:45.273200+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
```

---

**Original Post**:

My application works fine on Django local server. It deployed successfully to Heroku as well. But when I go to the website, it says application error.

I see a bunch of H10 and H14 error codes. I've tried updating the Procfile without the initial space. I've tried deleting and re-adding the requirements.txt file. Maybe it's something with the static files? One SO solution said delete a bunch of things from requirement.txt file that you don't need - as that worked for them. I just don't which ones to delete.

I can't add my **Heroku logs --tail** - SO thinks recognizes it as spam. If needed, I can email it to you. Please see below:

Comment: Is that all of the requirements your app needs? If yes, that's pretty small so no need to delete anything. Could you share the errors you're getting from the Heroku logs? You can use the Git CLI to access them with `heroku logs --tail`

Comment: @DjangoDev1 Yes this is all of the requirements my app needs. Please see above. I guess i 'm able to add the log now. Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Have you added the Heroku/Python buildpack? `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python`. Also, do you have `Pipfile` or `Pipfile.lock` in the project directory?

Comment: @DjangoDev1 yes i have the Heroku/Python buildpack. & Yes i have both Pipfile and Pipfile.lock in my project directory. I read somewhere to remove them from the project directory and then I got more errors... so i put them back

Comment: @DjangoDev1 should I try deleting Pipfile and Pipfile.lock again?

Comment: Yes, try and remove the from your project's directory and run `git push heroku main` without those 2 files. Just make sure you make a copy of them before removing them in case you need them.

Comment: @DjangoDev1 hi, please see my edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

None of my static files came through. That was all I had to run, so silly. I'm sure I tried this before, but for some reason it works now. Thanks for all your help @DjangoDev1